# Random motion of a person generated with forward and backwards steps with proper iterations

Tags: python, loops, iteration

My instructions:

-A person walks a random amount of steps forward, and then a different random number of steps backwards.
-The random steps are anywhere between 2 and 20
-The number of steps forward is always greater than the number of steps backwards
-That motion of forward / backward random steps repeats itself again and again
-The motion is consistent (the number of forward steps stays the same throughout the motion, and the number of backwards steps stays the same throughout the motion)
-After making a specific amount of total steps the person is told to stop and will be a certain amount of steps forward from where they started.

-The total number of steps is generated randomly and will be between 10 and 85

-You are writing a program to simulate the motion taken by the person.

-Display that motion and the number of steps he ends away from where he started.
For Example:

-If the program generated the forward steps to be 4, and the backward steps to be 2, and the total number of steps to be 13, your program would display:
FFFFBBFFFFBBF = 5 Steps from the start
-If the program generated the forward steps to be 5, and the backward steps to be 3, and the total steps to be 16, your program would display
FFFFFBBBFFFFFBBB = 4 Steps from the start

```
    import random

    x= random.randint(1,10)
    y= random.randint(1,10)
    total= random.randint(10,85)


    while True:
         counter = 2
         while counter < total:
            print("F", end="")
            counter = counter + 1
            total = total - 1
        if total == 0 or counter > total:
            break

        counter = 2
        while counter < total:
            print("B", end="")
            counter = counter + 1
            total = total - 1

        print("\nThe total amount of steps is", total)
        if total == 0 or counter > total:
            break
```

I tried making variables for total and x,y and adding and subtracting but I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. I broke the steps forward and backward into x,y. 1-10 each. My loop only works sometimes, printing the steps and the statement of the total steps. Most of the time it just prints FFFFFFF with no statement whatsoever. It also only prints stuff like FFFFFBBBBB and not FFFFBBFFFFBB etc. I'm in need of guidance or corrections on my code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need "infinite" loop if you know the total number of steps in advance? We can replace it with `for` loop that runs the exact number of steps.
While inside the loop we want to keep track of several things:

- current direction (`boolean` - true if moving forward)
- total displacement (number of forward steps minus backward steps)
- counter of steps in current direction

Here is the code that implements the above in a very straightforward (not very optimized) fashion for clarity.

```
import random

# backward cannot be greater than 9
# because it will break condition that forward should be greater
backward = random.randint(1, 9)

# forward has to be greater than backward
forward = random.randint(backward + 1, 10)
total = random.randint(10, 85)

# test for specific values
# forward, backward, total = 4, 2, 13

print(f"{forward} {backward} {total}")

forward_direction = True
displacement = 0
one_way = 0
string = []

for i in range(total):
    if forward_direction:
        one_way += 1
        displacement += 1
        # do we need to change direction?
        if one_way == forward:
            forward_direction = not forward_direction
            one_way = 0
        string.append('F')
    else:
        one_way += 1
        displacement -= 1
        if one_way == backward:
            forward_direction = not forward_direction
            one_way = 0
        string.append('B')

print(f'{"".join(string)} = {displacement}')
```

Result

> 4 2 13
>
> FFFFBBFFFFBBF = 5

By the way, you can solve this problem without loop for arbitrary input numbers  by using modulo operation.